# Cannot Dispose Image - Out of Memory

Tags: c#, .net, image, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

At first, I have an image (13-15Mb) and other five images that copy from the original image. After finishing my work, I want to dispose all images by click on a `Clear Data` button.

I use Diagnostic tools to know how memory works. As the result, the `dispose` method sometimes work, sometimes does not work. The memory still increases leading to out-of-memory exception even though I call `dispose` and `GC.Collect()` method. I don't know why it is unstable like that.

Below is my method to dispose data:

```
private void ResetDataPatient()
{
    GC.Collect();
    imgBox.Image.Dispose();
    imgBox.Image = Properties.Resources.defaultpicture;
    if (xrayPic != null)
    {
        xrayPic.Dispose();
    }
    if (rootPic != null)
    {
        rootPic.Dispose();
    }
    if (tmppic != null)
    {
        tmppic.Dispose();
    }
    if (tmppicCheck != null)
    {
        tmppicCheck.Dispose();
    }
    if (originalPic != null)
    {
        originalPic.Dispose();
    }
    if (PatienData != null)
    {
        PatienData.Clear();
        PatienData.Dispose();
        PatienData = null;
    }

    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set xrayPic, rootPic, tmppic, tmppicCheck and originalPic to null after disposing?

Comment: Do you actually get the oom exception or do you simply see the memory use rise and only fear if will lead to a oom excetopn? GC only kicks in when really necessary.. Aso what size is the 13MB: file or memory?

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki When I set all image to null after disposing, it worked. If I don't do that, it lead to out-of-memory exception. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to dispose images that are created from resources (e.g. from a file). If the copies are created using the `clone()` method, you don't need to dispose them. All you need is to clear your variables references by setting them to `null`. No need to call the `GC` manually:

```
private void ResetDataPatient() {
    imgBox.Image.Dispose();
    imgBox.Image = Properties.Resources.defaultpicture;
    if (xrayPic != null)
        xrayPic.Dispose();
    xrayPic = null;
    if (rootPic != null)
        rootPic.Dispose();
    rootPic = null;
    if (tmppic != null)
        tmppic.Dispose();
    tmppic = null;
    if (tmppicCheck != null)
        tmppicCheck.Dispose();
    tmppicCheck = null;
    if (originalPic != null)
        originalPic.Dispose();
    originalPic = null;
    if (PatienData != null) {
        PatienData.Clear();
        PatienData.Dispose();
        PatienData = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I set all image to null after disposing, it worked. If I don't do that, it lead to out-of-memory exception. Thank you so much!

Comment: Disposing the images will only free the resources, but the GC will not collect them if you still have references to them. GC will only reclaim memory that has no references (that's why it's called garbage), so when you set your variables to `null`, you're effectively letting the GC do its job.

Comment: In fact it's unnecessary to set the variables to null if they already are null, it's enough to put the set to null statement inside already present blocks after checking, if disposal of an instance is required.

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki Yes, that's obvious and programming basics. But as I mentioned at the top of my answer, there is no need to dispose images that are not from resources, in which case, the OP can remove the `null` check and dispose lines and leave the setting to `null` line. Either way, I like the code this way more that all those brackets. The redundant setting to `null` when already is `null` doesn't make a difference that we need to worry about or even waste time discussing. Choose the style that you like ;).

Answer (score 1):

Just set properties to null after disposing:

```
private void ResetDataPatient() {
    imgBox.Image.Dispose();
    imgBox.Image = Properties.Resources.defaultpicture;
    if (xrayPic != null)
    {
        xrayPic.Dispose();
        xrayPic = null;
    }
    if (rootPic != null)
    {
        rootPic.Dispose();
        rootPic = null;
    }
    if (tmppic != null)
    {
        tmppic.Dispose();
        tmppic = null;
    }
    if (tmppicCheck != null)
    {
        tmppicCheck.Dispose();
        tmppicCheck = null;
    }
    if (originalPic != null)
    {
        originalPic.Dispose();
        originalPic = null;
    }
    if (PatienData != null) {
        PatienData.Clear();
        PatienData.Dispose();
        PatienData = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Images are going to Large objects heap (LOH). If you are running 32-bit or lower framework version, than 4.5, you may be affected by that. Here is more information about .net 4.5 changes.
[LOH improvements in .NET 4.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2011/10/03/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5/)

Also you can try running this code to collect as much as possible ([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906200(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
```